# Jenkins CI - warning CS8032 - 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, warnings

I am testing a combinaison of Sonar / Jenkins for automated compilation and deployment of VS 2015 U3 project.

While testing the build I am gettting the following warning :

warning CS8032: Impossible de créer une instance de l'analyseur SonarAnalyzer.Rules.CSharp.DelegateSubtraction à partir de C:\Windows\TEMP.sonarqube.static\csharp_1.20.1\SonarAnalyzer-1.20.1.zip\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll : Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.. [E:\Jenkins\workspace\TraceParts.CAO\TPFileEngine\Projects\TPFileEngine\TrCADEngine\TrCADEngine.csproj]

In english it says that it can't create instance of SonarAnalyzer.Rules.CSharp.DelegateSubtraction from C:\Windows\TEMP.sonarqube.static\csharp_1.20.1\SonarAnalyzer-1.20.1.zip\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll  : can't load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependancy.

Why am I getting this warning ?
How could I get ride of this warning?

Thanks for your help